Binding data to reactive form in angular
I'm a student in IT and i have a little problem in my intership.
I have to modify an objet in the but before that i have to bind the data of the object in the form but my form control is not found.
Here is my form :
this.ficheForm = this.formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
      nomFiche: ['', Validators.required],
    })

Here is how i create the form :
if(questionNode.type==='CHECKBOX'){
            
    // Créer un FormArray pour les réponses de type CHECKBOX
    const formArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
    
    // Boucler sur les réponses et ajouter un FormControl pour chaque réponse
    questionNode.reponse.forEach(reponse => {
      const formControl = this.formBuilder.control([]);
      formArray.push(formControl);
    });
    
    // Ajouter le FormArray au FormGroup avec le nom de la question comme clé
    this.ficheForm.addControl(questionNode.id, formArray);

}else{
   this.ficheForm.addControl(questionNode.id, this.formBuilder.group({
     objet: ['', Validators.required],  // Premier champ requis
     reponse: ['']  // Deuxième champ optionnel
   }));
}

And now how i try to  bind data to the form :
if (this.ficheForm) {
    // Parcours des entrées de la map questionReponse
    for (let entry of Object.entries(this.reponses)) {
      let [questionId, reponseInfo] = entry;
      let [reponseId, responseValue] = Object.entries(reponseInfo)[0];

       // Get the corresponding form control
       const questionControl = this.ficheForm.controls[questionId];

       if (questionControl) {
         // Get the objet and reponse sub-controls
         const objetControl = questionControl.get('objet');
         const reponseControl = questionControl.get('reponse');
 
         if (objetControl && reponseControl) {
           // Set the values of the sub-controls
           objetControl.setValue(reponseId);
           reponseControl.setValue(responseValue);
 
           // Log values for verification
           console.log(objetControl.value);
           console.log(reponseControl.value);
         } else {
           console.error(`Object or response control for question ID ${questionId} not found.`);
         }
       } else {
         console.error(`Form control for question ID ${questionId} not found.`);
       }
     }
   } else {
     console.error('Form group not initialized.');
   }

To bind the data in my form i take the data from a Map<string, Map<string, string>>
And here is my result :
(https://i.sstatic.net/Cb3YQnCr.png)
Thanks for your time and your help.
